# While Debugging in VS, can I change the HTTP Header server tag?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2013, http-headers

I have an MVC project that I've written and tested in VS 2013.  When I test and debug the application from Visual Studio, my application has rendered correctly.  However, when I published my application to it's hosting server, the page isn't rendering and styling correctly from the server.

Upon inspecting the page source and headers, the only difference that I found is that in Visual Studio, IIS Express is passing the HTTP header property:

> Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0

However, on the server that I published to, the server outputs:

> Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5

I am not sure if this is the cause of my root problem but I need to be able to locally duplicate this scenario so that I can take the results to my sysadmin who manages the server.

Is there a way that I can fudge this HTTP header property?

For clarification, this is an MVC5 application, targeting .Net 4.5.2 and the server that I am publishing to is running Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to change it, but it is [possible to remove the Server header entirely](https://www.troyhunt.com/shhh-dont-let-your-response-headers/), which would in effect give you synchronization between your servers (provided you remove it on both of them).